# SQL Server's db_datareader can be updated

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a database called "DB_A".

This DB_A server is not a server I created, but a server that took over management.

But there was a problem.

<Problem encountered 1.>

- I want to create an account that can only select in this DB_A.
- So I created an account called "select_A" and only gave the db_datareader permission.
- However, the account "select_A" can also be updated.

* I created a new Database "TEST" and a new Login "select_B".
* The default DataBase is set to "master" without any manipulation of "select_B". With the server role set to public, both select, update, and insert are possible in the "TEST" database.

- When tested with the same settings on my personal PC, both select_A and select_B Login cannot be updated.
- I really want to solve the problem that occurred. I need help.

I compared the settings of my local PC and DB Login.
I didn't find any difference in Login settings on the server that had a problem with my local PC.

I want to get help with which part I should check.

Comment: *"both select_A and select_B Login cannot be updated."* What does this mean? I *assume* you ran some SQL to `ALTER` the `LOGIN` and it failed? What was the error?

Comment: My native language was not English, but the expression was awkward.

When my local PC only gave db_datatreader permission to select_A Login, select_A login cannot be updated. This is the right state.

However, my company server gave only db_datareader permission to select_A Login. Update should not be possible, but update is possible. This is a problematic state.

I want to know the cause of this problem.

Comment: When you added the db_datareader role to the select_A user, did you remove the (default) public role? While it's not possible to `grant all on dbo.Table_A to db_datareader` it is possible to `grant all on dbo.Table_A to public` so update access could be available due to that.

Comment: * I found the cause.
* I don't know who's executed, but the Public authority was granted Server's Control permissions.

* Revoke Control Server to [Public] AS [SA] This was solved.